# Correct structure of "...as....as" sentence

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct structure when I use......as....as in a sentence?

1. **No poet** is as renowned as William Wordsworth is.
2. **No other poet** is as renowned as William Wordsworth is.

My grammar books says and many websites also say that **2** is grammatically correct though I have seen both are used in daily conversations by both native and non native speakers. Can anyone please explain If **1** is grammatical and if I can use both?

Comment: Both are OK. In full, 1 means  "No poet is as renowned as William Wordsworth is renowned".

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, only 2 is correct. Since "William Wordsworth" is a poet himself, you can't say "he is not as renowned as he is", that's just plain wrong.

However, in daily conversation, I also hear a lot of 1 spoken. Daily speech tends to be less strict in grammar. So if you say 1 it's easily understood by people as when you do such a negative comparison, the object being compared to is implicitly excluded.

Comment: That's not how 1 is interpreted. It means "No poet is as renowned as William Wordsworth is (renowned)" is fine.

Comment: Hi Bill, If don't add "other", does it mean "William Wordsworth is not a poet"?

Comment: @user254288 No! The word "other" is optional here.

Comment: +1 If you want to be *precise* in terms of logic, then you're quite right that *other* should be used. As a *practical* concern, it's not normally needed. But in *some* contexts it's essential. (I'm thinking of riddles and other English-derived puzzles where strict literalism is required.)